# How to scroll to top of the page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to scroll to the top of the page after getting an ajax call response using angularjs. Basically, I am displaying alert messages on top of the page and I want to focus the alert message as the ajax response received.

Thanks

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can use

```
$window.scrollTo(x, y);
```

where `x` is the pixel along the horizontal axis and `y` is the pixel along the vertical axis.

1. *Scroll to top*

   ```
   $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   ```
2. *Focus on element*

   ```
   $window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('put here your element').offsetTop);
   ```

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/7kevR9WUJTNH7h5R6VVS?p=preview)

**Update**:

Also you can use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/LnbDff2bK7zw8FsSorll?p=preview)

Comment: For focusing on element, `$window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('put here your element').offset().top);`

Comment: dont forget to inject $window in controller function definition.
for example:
function ($scope, $rootScope, $location,
        base_factory,$window)

Comment: @MuhammadReda when you say put here your element' is that the id of the element? for example I want to scroll to the top of an element with id of "directions_panel" so I entered that where you say 'put here your element' however I am getting an error. thanks for any help

Comment: @MuhammadReda I have it working now thanks. Instead of angular.element('put your element here').offsetTop I did document.getElementById('my_element').offsetTop. thanks for the help :)

Comment: I don't know why but these both codes are not working. I'm using it with ng-calendar directive. :(

Answer (score 31):

You can use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

Just inject `$anchorScroll` as a dependency, and call `$anchorScroll()` whenever you want to scroll to top.

Comment: Note that there's no animation (smooth scroll) available for `$anchorScroll`.

Answer (score 13):

Ideally we should do it from either controller or directive as per applicable. 
Use `$anchorScroll`, `$location` as dependency injection.

Then call this two method as

```
$location.hash('scrollToDivID');
$anchorScroll();
```

Here `scrollToDivID` is the id where you want to scroll.

Assumed you want to navigate to a error message div as

```
<div id='scrollToDivID'>Your Error Message</div>
```

For more information please see this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Comment: The above answer is for angularjs 1

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget you can also use pure JavaScript to deal with this situation, using:

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
 });
```

Answer (score -4):

use: `$anchorScroll();`

with `$anchorScroll` property

Comment: The answer should be descriptive.