# Angular1 perfect scrollbar : After refreshing the data, how to get it back to the top

Tags: angularjs, perfect-scrollbar

I set the scroll bar for the table. When I scroll to the bottom of the current page and click on the next page, the scroll position does not get back to the top. How can I get it back to the top after the data is refreshed? Thanks.

Comment: Please have look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871434/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-the-page-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

It could be done a lot of ways, how are you handling pagination? You could place a ng-click on the pagination button that scrolls you to the top. A code sample or plunkr would be helpful.

You could do something like below using regular JS.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('x');
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var i = 10;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, i);
    i += 10;
    if (i == 200) clearInterval(int);
  }, 20);
})
body {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 600px;
}
```

\HTML in view layer

```
<button id='x'>click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is valid.